# Gram–Schmidt process

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I got to use the Gram–Schmidt process on this set: $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$ 
I only know how to deal with vectors but not with matrices. Anyone can show me how to do that?

Comment: Ghram Schimdt process works **ONLY** in coverting basis vectors to an orthogonal set of basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The Gram-Schmidt process is defined for any inner product space, and the process is exactly the same. So you just need to know what is the inner product being used on $M_{3\times3}$. This is usually the Frobenius inner product:

$$
\langle A, B \rangle = tr(AB^T).
$$

(Here 'tr' means trace.)

Answer (score 0):

You use the same process than with vectors, but the inner product with matrices is : $$\langle M_1,M_2\rangle=\mathrm{Tr}(M_2^*M_1)$$